# ionic setup sass throw error like this, how to fix?

Tags: sass, ionic-framework

> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\artory>ionic setup sass

**You have specified Ionic CLI to set up sass.
However, you do not have Gulp installed globally. Please run `npm install -g gul
p`**
*Ionic setup complete*

when I try to fix this issue, then it stop here.

> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\artory>npm install -g gulp

and after a long time, it display a lot of errors, I dont know why, please help me.

Comment: can you please update question with error log?? I mean what errors is it displaying actully?